# Audio recording meter similar to apple voice control meter iphone

Tags: iphone, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder

I am an IOS developer and wanna replicate the recording effect of iPhone voice control app within my audio recording app.
any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? (Have you read the relevant iOS class reference docs?) You really need to get started and then ask more directed questions when/if you get stuck. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use an `AVAudioRecorder` to record the sound.
Then just
`[audioRecorder setMeteringEnabled:YES]`
and then just read
`[audioRecorder averagePowerForChannel:1]`

You can find more info about `AVAudioRecorder` in the Apple documentation: [AVAudioPlayer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: You may use [this](https://github.com/mike-dutka/gl-data-visualization-view) to visualize data (sound levels) which you got from `[audioRecorder averagePowerForChannel:x]` as @
Andrei Stoleru says. You should just add GLDataVisualizationView, set visualization type as VU meter and set value to visualize. There are also iPhone sample project.